# Merging and group two arrays containing objects based on one identifying column value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping, stdclass

I have a trouble regarding merging arrays by specific scenario. Searching for similar cases gave no results here. To understand clearly what is my requirements, please look at the next example:

```
$array1 = [
    (object) ['call_date' => '2013-10-22 00:00:00', 'first_amount' => 10],
    (object) ['call_date' => '2013-10-23 00:00:00', 'first_amount' => 20],
];

$array2 = [
    (object) ['call_date' => '2013-10-22 00:00:00', 'second_amount' => 30],
    (object) ['call_date' => '2013-10-24 00:00:00', 'second_amount' => 40],
];
```

What I need as the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass
        (
            [call_date] => 2013-10-22 00:00:00
            [first_amount] => 10
            [second_amount] => 30
        )

    [1] => stdClass
        (
            [call_date] => 2013-10-23 00:00:00
            [first_amount] => 20
        )

    [2] => stdClass
        (
            [call_date] => 2013-10-24 00:00:00
            [second_amount] => 40
        )
)
```

So as you can see merging goes by **call_date**. Items from the first and the second array which are under the date `2013-10-22 00:00:00` was combined, item from the second array under the date `2013-10-24 00:00:00` was appended.

Tried a lot of combinations of **array_merge, array_udiff, array_merge_recursive, array_map**, but nothing helped.

Comment: A for each, with a test condition? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php . All those functions are just foreach.

Comment: The array functions won’t be particularly helpful here – since you don’t _have_ arrays inside your arrays, but objects. So you will have to append attributes to an existing object or create a new object, whether or not one with the call_date already exists in your first array.

Comment: Just a `foreach` using the `call_date` as the key of a new array, if an item does not exist, add, if it does, add the `*_amount` column (or just `$newarray[$item->call_date] = (object)array_merge(get_object_vars($newarray[$item->call_date]),get_object_vars($item));` (You're talking about merging _object_ here.

Comment: @Remi, thanks for the answer. So what is the most optimal way of using foreach? Should I use nested foreach-s?

Comment: No, just 1 foreach in succession for every array you want to add to it.(so `foreach($array1 as $item){..}foreach($array2 as $item){..}` etc.)

Comment: @CBroe, I can convert objects to arrays, it's not the main problem, you can consider array instead of stdClass.

Comment: @Riddick No optimal way for such basic language feature. Propose some code, then we can talk more !

Comment: Well then I don’t see any real problem with this … you just check if there is an element for the call_date already, and append the new value to it or create a new one. You should really give this a try yourself, because as of now your question is basically just asking for code.

Comment: What about : array_unique ? array_unique($array1 + $array2 + $array3) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @Jahnux73, already have tried, not helped as it removes only full duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple scenario:

1. change array keys
2. merge recursive
3. map merged elements back to object (stdClass)

Example:

```
//change key
$workFirstArray = array_combine(
    array_map(function($object) { return $object->call_date;}, $firstArray), $firstArray
);
$workSecondArray = array_combine(
    array_map(function($object) { return $object->call_date;}, $secondArray), $secondArray
);

//map merged elements back to StdClass
$result = array_map(function($element) {
        if(is_array($element)) {
            $element['call_date'] = end($element['call_date']);
            $element=(object)$element;
        }
        return $element;
    },
    array_merge_recursive($workFirstArray, $workSecondArray)
);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [call_date] => 2013-10-22 00:00:00
            [first_amount] => 10
            [second_amount] => 40
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [call_date] => 2013-10-23 00:00:00
            [second_amount] => 30
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [call_date] => 2013-10-24 00:00:00
            [second_amount] => 40
        )

)
```

Comment: WOW, that worked, and quite fast! Thank you very much! Added just one thing to complete your solution:
`$result = array_values($result);`

Comment: While I don't personally endorse this answer (because I don't like the indirect nature of bouncing to array-type to merge then back to object-type data), the initial two steps of producing temporary first level associative keys can be simplified by a more modern technique. [`array_column($firstArray, null, 'call_date')`](https://3v4l.org/E75oc)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$result = $firstArray;
for ($i=0; $i < count($firstArray); $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j < count($secondArray); $j++){
        if ($firstArray[$i]['call_date'] == $secondArray[$j]['call_date']){
            $result[$i]['second_amount'] = $secondArray[$j]['second_amount'];
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($j == count($secondArray))
        $result[] = $secondArray[$j-1];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Your solution expects fixed indexes (as second_amount), but it must be independent of them.

Comment: This unexplained answer fails to respect the integral aspect of this question that the input arrays contain objects (not arrays).  This snippet [does not work](https://3v4l.org/mlDeG).

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $first;
$amounts = array('first_amount','second_amount');
foreach ($first as $fKey => $f) {
    foreach ($second as $sKey => $s) {
        if ($f['call_date'] == $s['call_date']) {
            foreach ($amounts as $amount) {
                if (!isset($f[$amount]) && isset($s[$amount]))
                    $result[$fKey][$amount] = $s[$amount];
            }
            unset($second[$sKey]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
$result = array_merge($result, $second);
```

if you have more keys add on amounts array, if you want replace existing keys remove `!isset($f[$amount]) &&` from condition and you have more than one equal call_date remove `break;` too.

Comment: This answer fails to respect the integral aspect of this question that the input arrays contain objects (not arrays).  This snippet [does not work](https://3v4l.org/fFXdm).

Answer (score 0):

Because objects require slightly different handling than arrays, you cannot [simply use array-merging techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73106011/2943403) with objects.  In my opinion, it is best to merge the two arrays, then iterate the rows/objects.

While iterating, generate a new array where the group-identifying value is used as the first level key.

Objects do not need to be temporarily cast as arrays, then reverted back to their initial object type -- I find this approach to be indirectly and likely to be inefficient.

Another difference between arrays and objects is that arrays do not require their parent element to be declared when pushing with square brace syntax, but with objects, you must declare the parent object before pushing children into it.

Below I use the Null Coalescing Assignment Operator (`??=`) as a way of only declaring an empty parent object if the parent object has not yet been declared.

Push each property (key&value) of each object into its group.  When finished, you can remove the first level associative keys with `array_values()`.

([Demo of both snippets below](https://3v4l.org/1JZsV)) ([or Demo replacing `??=` with `isset()` condition](https://3v4l.org/pnQhf))

Functional-style code:

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            array_merge($array1, $array2),
            function($result, $obj) {
                $result[$obj->call_date] ??= (object) [];
                foreach ($obj as $prop => $val) {
                    $result[$obj->call_date]->$prop = $val;
                }
                return $result;
            }
        )
    )
);
```

or without null coalescing assignment

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            array_merge($array1, $array2),
            function($result, $obj) {
                if (!isset($result[$obj->call_date])) {
                    $result[$obj->call_date] = $obj;
                } else {
                    foreach ($obj as $prop => $val) {
                        $result[$obj->call_date]->$prop = $val;
                    }
                }
                return $result;
            }
        )
    )
);
```

Classic foreach:

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $obj) {
    $result[$obj->call_date] ??= (object) [];
    foreach ($obj as $prop => $val) {
        $result[$obj->call_date]->$prop = $val;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

or without null coalescing assignment

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $obj) {
    if (!isset($result[$obj->call_date])) {
        $result[$obj->call_date] = $obj;
    } else {
        foreach ($obj as $prop => $val) {
            $result[$obj->call_date]->$prop = $val;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

I do not endorse the use of a loop of one array inside another loop of the other array UNLESS the group-identifying value is a data type that will be mutated when used as an array key.  (for instance, a float value will be floored as an integer when used as a key)