# How get a object by id from arrays of object?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, object, multidimensional-array

Assuming that I have an array of objects like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10-423-1176
            [qty] => 2
            [price] => 12.6
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 26-295-1006
            [qty] => 24
            [price] => 230.35
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12-330-1000
            [qty] => 2
            [price] => 230.35
        )
```

And I have another array of object hat looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item Object
        (
            [internalId] => 14062
            [itemVendorCode] => 89-605-1250
        )

    [1] => Item Object
        (
            [internalId] => 33806
            [itemVendorCode] => 89-575-2354
        )

    [2] => Item Object
        (
            [internalId] => 64126
            [itemVendorCode] => 26-295-1006
        )
)
```

I want to loop through the 2nd array of objects and get the 'itemVendorCode' and then use it as the 'id' to get the object from the first array of objects. Is there a way to obtain what I want without looping the first array? Looping is very costly in my use-case.

Comment: To avoid looping use the value of `itemVendorCode` field as key in the first array when you fill it (in a loop, of course :-) )

Comment: @Clement Canaria, that a look to this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903022/how-get-a-object-by-id-from-arrays-of-object/28903718#comment46069673_28903803

Comment: @Clemen what is your exact desired output? Do just want to filter the first array or do you need to specifically relate the first array data to each row of the second array?

Comment: Perhaps [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652506/merging-and-group-two-arrays-containing-objects-based-on-one-identifying-column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use loops in any case, even if those loops are hidden within PHP built-in functions.

For instance:

```
$codes = array_map(function ($item) { return $item->itemVendorCode; }, $array2);
$items = array_filter($array1, function ($item) use ($codes) { return in_array($item->id, $codes); });
// $items contains only elements from $array1 that match on $array2
```

If this will be more efficient than using regular loops is hard to tell.

Since you are aparently trying to code what is supposed to be a DBMS's job, I recommend you export those tables to a database server such as MySQL instead and let it work its magic on those "JOINs".

Answering your comment, you could merge with something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $item1)
    foreach ($array2 as $item2)
        if ($item1->id == $item2->itemVendorCode)
            $result[] = (object)array_merge((array)$item1, (array)$item2));
```

`$result` will contain a new set of objects that merge properties from both `$array1` and `$array2` where they intersect in `id == itemVendorCode`.

Comment: ok this seems to work but I'll have to check the results first. thank you.

Comment: is there a way to just merge the 2 arrays using 'id' (array1)  and 'itemVendorCode' (array2). and eliminating object from array1 that doesn't exist in array2?The result would look like:

[11731] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 90-423-5430
            [internalId] => 64126
            [qty] => 22
            [price] => 1.16
        )

Comment: @Clemen . This is a good answer. However the initial question clearly said _"..Is there a way to obtain what I want without looping the first array..."_ I am not accusing you for a accepting this answer, but other users here have tried to give you the correct answers following that constraint you suggested yet you accepted this one. Be sure to stick with what you are asking for in the future

Comment: @CodeGodie Well, the code can be easily rewritten to use `array_map()` instead of loops, but thats rather pointless. As I stated in my answer, there will be loops envolved either you explicitly use them or not.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need first arrays index keys? if not you could iterate throuh first array once and set key to `id`. Something like:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $items[$item->id] = $item;
    unset($items[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array_map` and `array_filter()` function to achieve that.

Try with this code:

```
<?php

$first = array();
$first[0] = new stdClass;
$first[0]->id = '89-605-1250';
$first[0]->qty = 2;
$first[0]->price = 12.6;

$first[1] = new stdClass;
$first[1]->id = '89-575-2354';
$first[1]->qty = 24;
$first[1]->price = 230.35;


$last = array();
$last[0] = new stdClass;
$last[0]->internalId = 14062;
$last[0]->itemVendorCode = '89-605-1250';

$last[1] = new stdClass;
$last[1]->internalId = 33806;
$last[1]->itemVendorCode = '89-575-2354';

$ids = array_map(function($element){return $element->itemVendorCode;}, $last);

$to_find = $ids[0];

$object = array_filter($first, function($element){global $to_find; return $element->id == $to_find ? true: false;})[0];

print_r($object);

?>
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 89-605-1250
    [qty] => 2
    [price] => 12.6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another direct approach to solve this problem, even better than the one I proposed earlier:

```
// you got the $itemVendorCode from looping through the second array, let say :

$itemVendorCode = "89-605-1250";


// I'm assuming that you converted the array of objects in into accessible multidimensional array

// so the $first_array would look like :

$first_array= array (
        array (
                "id" => "10-423-1176",
                "qty" => 2,
                "price" => 12.6 
        ),
        array (
                "id" => "10-423-1176",
                "qty" => 5,
                "price" => 25 
        ),
        array (
                "id" => "89-605-1250",
                "qty" => 12,
                "price" => 30 
        ) 
);

// Now you can filter the first array using 

$filter = function ($player) use($itemVendorCode) {
    return $player ['id'] == $itemVendorCode;
};

$filtered = array_filter ( $first_array, $filter );


// print the price of the matching filtered item 

print $filtered[key($filtered)]['price'] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using array_search:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$item) {
    $firstArrayObjectKey = array_search($item['itemVendorCode'], $array1);
    //... do something with the key $firstArrayObjectKey
}
```

Comment: I dont think that will work as arr1 is a multidimensional array

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my problem but I'm afraid I would have to agree with @CodeGodie. Thanks anyway.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'll need to loop through the first array to get the itemVendorCode.

Right after that you can use the itemValue you got from the previous process to search in a reduced array of the first object using array_reduce function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php