# Merge arrays of associative arrays by shared column values

Tags: php, arrays, merge, grouping

I want to merge two arrays based on a common column value. Here are my 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = [
    [
        "total_process_per_category" => "6",
        "category_id" => "1"
    ],
    [
        "total_process_per_category" => "2",
        "category_id" => "2"
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    [
        "total_pinned_per_category" => "16",
        "category_id" => "1"
    ],
    [
        "total_pinned_per_category" => "4",
        "category_id" => "2"
    ]
];
```

I want to merge these arrays to get:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'total_process_per_category' => '6',
    'total_pinned_per_category' => '16',
    'category_id' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'total_process_per_category' => '2',
    'total_pinned_per_category' => '4',
    'category_id' => '2',
  ),
)
```

As you can see, the two arrays have the same key ['category_id'] and same value as well.

I want to make a result where ['total_process_per_category'] and ['total_pinned_per_category'] are placed together on the same array based on their ['category_id'] value.

I got this using a nested foreach, but it looks so ugly.  Please show me a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try `array_reduce`:

```
$someVariable = 'someValue';
$result = array_reduce(array_merge($array1, $array2), function ($carry, $item) use ($someVariable) {
    if (isset($carry[$item['category_id']])) {
        $carry[$item['category_id']] = array_merge($carry[$item['category_id']], $item);
    } else {
        $carry[$item['category_id']] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, array());

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without an "ugly nested foreach". Merge the two arrays before iterating, the group by the category_id values.  After the loop, clear away the temporary first-level keys with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1lu5T)) ([array_reduce() version](https://3v4l.org/vpehc))

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $row) {
    $result[$row['category_id']] = ($result[$row['category_id']] ?? []) + $row;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'total_process_per_category' => '6',
    'category_id' => '1',
    'total_pinned_per_category' => '16',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'total_process_per_category' => '2',
    'category_id' => '2',
    'total_pinned_per_category' => '4',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like:

```
foreach ( $array1 as $index => $value ) {
    $mergeArray[] = [ $value, $array2[$index]];
}
```