# PHP combine array with matching items

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays that are this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 17-3-2018
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 16-3-2018
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 15-3-2018
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => 14-3-2018
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day] => 15-3-2018
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day] => 17-3-2018
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

I am trying to combine them so that I get a third array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 17-3-2018
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 16-3-2018
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 15-3-2018
            [count] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => 14-3-2018
        )
)
```

I have tried array_merge and array_combine but they are not giving me the results I am looking for, I am a beginner at PHP so I am a bit lost trying to work out the best solution.

I asked a previous question which I have now deleted and this one has a simplified array which I am hoping will make things easier.

Do I need to loop through each item and check against the other to build the new array?

Comment: Might this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35475526/2086717

Comment: @jsmitter3 not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the second array and search a flat array of array1.
Create the flat array with array_column.

```
// Create a flat day array you can search
$day= array_column($arr1, "day");


Foreach($arr2 as $val){
    // Find if day is in $arr1
    $find = array_search($val['day'], $day);
    // If day is found in $arr1 add count value
    If($find !== false) $arr1[$find]['count'] = $val['count'];

}

Var_dump($arr1);
```

https://3v4l.org/fQKqj